# Create Session, Establish Variable and Transfer Variable to Next Page

Tags: php, session, session-variables

This page I am working on has a list of links which I do not want to append url variables (.html?id=12345), so I thought it might be worth a shot to try sessions for the first time.

The page does a query to the database, gets the rows and then displays them in a list.  The problem that I am running into is that the session variable is being overwritten by the next row in the while results.  So the session carries the last variable on the page regardless of what the user clicks.

I am thinking that it is an issue of the placement of the code (rearranging), but I have had no luck yet getting this to properly pass the correct variable to the next page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
$tourQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * table WHERE ID = '".$page['main_id']."' AND DateTime >= CurDate() ORDER BY DateTime ASC");
$tourcount = mysql_num_rows($tourQuery);
while($tour = mysql_fetch_array($tourQuery))
    {
        $_SESSION['sessionname'] = $tour['EventID'];
    ?>
            <div class="schedule-row vevent" style="overflow:auto;"> 
                <div class="schedule-button">
                    <a class="schedlink url" href="<?=$pg['request']?>.html">
                        View
                    </a>
                </div>
                <br clear="all" /> 
            </div>
<?php       
}
```

So as you can see, a session variable is being determined for each result from the query, I am just trying to figure out how to pass that to the next page rather than the last variable on the page.

If you think the code from the next page is relevant, I can provide it, however, everything seemingly works on this page so I thought it would make sense to focus on the code above.

so, please help me.

Comment: That's not how sessions work. `$_SESSION` is an array that is shared between requests. You can put anything in it, including `key => value` pairs. But you need to somehow associate links with a session items. You do that using GET or POST data. Meaning `$_SESSION` is redundant here. Stick with `?EventID=$tour['EventID']`.

Comment: if you dont want to go with `GET` then definitely you have to choose `POST` method because using session you can not uniquely identify the ids to show the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to add variables to the url and there is no relation between the page `$pg['request']` and the value `$tour['EventID']` in the loop, the only way to send the user to the next page with the corresponding value, is to use a form, post it and add `$tour['EventID']` as a (hidden) form field.

Something like:

```
<form action="<?php echo $pg['request']; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $tour['EventID']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="View">
</form>
```

(you might need to encode / cast your variables to be able to `echo` them out without problems)

Comment: I like this idea... I'm going to give this a try.

Comment: So can this be done with keeping the text link?  I would prefer not to have a submit button.

Comment: @NotJay You can use a `<button>` if the `<input>` does not give you enough possibilities to style it with css. But I think either could look just like a link.

Comment: This is almost working... The page that the variable is being passed to is a php page but we used .htaccess to change the end of the url to .html instead of .php.  The variable is not displaying on the 2nd page.  Is there a chance that this could be due to the .html extension?  Also, use $_POST to get the variable?

Comment: @NotJay `POST` variables are passed normally when you rewrite a url unless you do a redirect like `http://www....` instead of a rewrite like `/path/to/file.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
$_SESSION['sessionname'] = $tour['EventID'];
```

Use this:

```
$_SESSION['EventID'][$tour['EventID']] = $tour['EventID'];
```

or

```
$_SESSION['Events'][$tour['EventID']] = $tour;
```

You don't need a session name if you don't manage cookies.